# Qt timestamps from Epoch(1970) to Postgresql timestamps that starts in 2000. How to add an offset and convert from milliseconds to microseconds?

Tags: postgresql, qt, timestamp, offset, epoch

I need to compute the offset from 1970 to 2000 to insert data into postgresql database because postgresql start at 2000 in microseconds resolution and currentMSecsSinceEpoch starts in 1970 in milliseconds. ¿How can an offset be added in order to display the same date in postgresql database?

Comment: Can you tell us where you have a problem in your code? When you use QDateTime and timestamp as data types you don't need to convert anything. So what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I did not explain it... When I save data to postgresql database the 0 time starts at  "2000-01-01 00:00:00"; But in the Qt application it starts at "1970-01-01 00:00:00";. Also the resolution is different as mentioned. So before saving the timestamp to postgresql database I need to compute the difference between 1970 and 2000 or postgresql will save things at 2050, with 30 years of difference... I posted the solution I've used but if there is another solution will be great to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for computing the offset and converting to microseconds is shown:

```
    QString timestamp =  "2000-01-01 00:00:00"; //postgres starts here and uses microseconds resolution
    QString timestampEpoch =  "1970-01-01 00:00:00"; //epoch starts here, Qt has seconds/milliseconds resolution.
    //need to compute the interval between these dates in microseconds
    QString format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";//TZD";
    QDateTime origin =  QDateTime::fromString(timestampEpoch, format);
    QDateTime end = QDateTime::fromString(timestamp, format);
    qint64 offset = origin.msecsTo(end);
    qint64 timeWithOffset = 1000 * (QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - offset); //mseconds to microseconds for postgresql timestamp(8 bytes)
```

Hope it helps!